# How to delete a user if he is alone in category in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `students` and another table called `categories`. They are related with the `category_id` row. 
My category table has rows:

```
1 - VIP
2 - Loyal
3 - Neutral
```

I want to delete every student which is alone in category.
If I have 5 students which are VIP and one which is Loyal.

How to delete the Loyal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

group by the `category_id` and select only those categories that have only one student. Get the `id` from that student and put it in the delete query.

```
delete from students
where id in
(
   select * from
   (
      select min(id)
      from students
      group by category_id
      having count(*) = 1
   ) tmp
)
```

You need another subquery in between, because you can't select from a table you are deleting from at the same time (in MySQL). So you need to build a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `join`.  Here is one method:

```
delete s
    from students join
          (select category_id
           from students s
           group by category_id
           having count(*) = 1
          ) sc
          on s.category_id = sc.category_id;
```